# Can this be modeled in a state machine pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I wanted to model a game (for practice reasons) using a state machine design pattern involving the following states:

- Initial: The game-host sets up the game with some configuration parameters
- Published: The game is visible to other players, so that they can join
- Ready: As soon as the game is full (maximum number of players are reached), the host can start the game
- Running: The game is running
- Finished: The game is over, players can see some statistics about the game

However, after reading up on the state machine pattern, it appears to me that it is only applicable when the states all expose a common interface (e.g. the `handleInput`-method in this article: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).

What I intended to have is for the Game to have a `publish` method in the initial state, that will guide it into the `Published` state, where it then has a `join` method, which will guide it to `Ready` once enough players have joined, and so on.

The goal is to separate concerns here, I don't want a huge `Game` class having to deal with gathering all the players as well as handling the actual game logic.

Can this be done with a state machine? Or is there any other design pattern I could use for this?

Comment: Your state logic seems very linear. That is, you don't have odd cases where you can start in the Initial state and progress to the Running state. When you have complex state transition logic, it can result in monolithic case or if/then blocks to decide how to handle transitions. The state pattern is a cleaner alternative. Since you don't have that complexity, I think state pattern is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `states` expose a common interface but, this has nothing to do with your actual *game*.

The minimum requirement is to have the set of `transitions` from one `state` to the next and a mechanism to create the resulting `state` based on the previous `state` and the `transition`. The common interface deals only with this aspect.

For your initial `state`, the host sets some values on a `GameConfig` object. Pressing a "Publish" button is the transition to the next state. On the transition handler you need to create a `GameLobby` object.

The `GameLobby` is created with the game's name and expected number of players and deals strictly with adding players and other lobby related functions (such as player chat, which should also be implemented in their own class).

Here, the transition handler is called each time a player joins the lobby. Only when the total number of players is reached do you transition to the next state, "Game Ready". (If the number of playes is not yet equal to the requirements you can transition to a new `GameLobby` object with one extra player if you want to keep things immutable.)

Along with the `GameConfig` object, this new state contains a list of `Player` objects.

From this state, when the host clicks "Ready", in your transition handler you finally create your `GameLogic` object, based on the `GameConfig` object and the list of `Player` objects.

When the game is won, you transition to the "Finished" state which contains the game's statistics and a final transition to "end program".

Each of these main states can, in turn, contain their own state machines.

So, the state machine related interfaces do not restrict the interfaces of the payload.

I also recommend you separate the part related to displaying items on the screen from the part that determines "what" to display. So, each of those state objects would have something like an `Init` method where they generate a list of `sprites` that need to be displayed (and attaches any event handlers that are needed for the transitions). A separate object would then take that list and show it on the screen and call the even handlers on user input.

Comment: If the OP wants to practice the state pattern, I guess this is OK. But I don't see the benefit of the added complexity of the state pattern. Since the state transitions appear to be linear, you could just have an enumeration variable GAME_STATE and advance it at each phase. Much less code, easier to understand. KISS is a pattern, too.

Comment: Plenty examples of more complex states in a game here, that might be better with a state pattern: http://jessewarden.com/2012/07/finite-state-machines-in-game-development.html

Comment: @Fuhrmanator It often happens that the definition of "simple" varies as a project advances. No project is ever free from scope creep, not even practice ones. This pattern, while making future changes easier, also forces you to organize your project and separate responsibilities. This, in turn, increases the odds of a successful project.

Comment: Are you familiar with [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)? Nothing wrong with modeling the states in a state diagram.